# Determine and sketch the equivalence class

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have already determined the equivalence class, but I do not know how to draw/sketch it.

> On the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ let R be the relation given by 
>   $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}R\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix} :\iff x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2$.

Now, I have to determine and sketch the equivalence class of $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}$.

**Here is my solution:**

$(-1)^2+2^2=5$. Thus $5=x_1^2+x_2^2$ must apply.

$\implies x_1=\pm\sqrt{5-x_2}$

$\implies \begin{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\pm\sqrt{5-x_2}\\2\end{pmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$

How can I sketch this in a coordinate system now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If you take an element $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ in this equivalence class, how far from the origin is that point?

Comment: $x_1$ x-units and $x_2$ y-units? I appreciate your answer, but I am still not sure how to draw the equivalence class. Is it simply a circle from -5 to 5 on the x-axis?

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake $-\sqrt5$ and $\sqrt5$, but otherwise, yes. You do get a circle with radius $\sqrt5$ centered at the origin.

Comment: OK, thank you. What about the $y/x_2$ values? One is 2 and the other one -2?

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake Well, yes. The vertical line $x_1=-1$ will intersect the circle twice. Once in $(-1,2)$, and once in $(-1,-2)$. And you can easily check that these are both in the relevant equivalence class.